# Is it possible for there to be an independent Constable?

Tags: england-and-wales, police, constable

The office of police Constable is independent of the employing police force. In theory then one could hold the office but not be within the organisation of any police force. Does anything prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is no current way to be appointed to this office, other than within the ambit of some police force. That is because although the origin of the "office of constable" is in the common law, <sup>1</sup> the mode of appointment to that office has long been regulated by statute law.<sup>2</sup> There is no statute which lets somebody become a constable other than as part of some police force, and any residual common-law power has been effaced by the current statutory regimes for policing and local government.

Before the current system of larger territorial police forces covering the whole country, it was possible for a justice of the peace to appoint a constable. This might be regarded as a very small police force. The key legislation here is the [Parish Constables Act 1842](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Vict/5-6/109/pdfs/ukpga_18420109_en.pdf), the important bits of which for our purposes are:

1. Section 11, which allows JPs to choose people to serve in the office of constable, from a list drawn up under other provisions of the Act. These people must take the oath specified in Section 12.
2. Section 15, which says that if the new constable is in a county which has a "Chief Constable or Superintendent" then he shall be "subject to the Authority" of that person. At the time, this was true in some but not all places. So even in 1842 he might end up being part of a larger police force.
3. Section 21, which removes all previous common-law offices which overlap with that of constable as regulated in the Act. It says that "no Petty Constable, Headborough, Borsholder, Tithingman or Peace Officer of the like Description under any Name of Office, shall be appointed for any Parish, Township or Vill within the Limits of this Act, except for the Performance of Duties unconnected with the Preservation of the Peace". There are various savings relating to the then-existing statutory police forces. But generally this takes away any previously-existing power to appoint a constable-like person, under whatever name, in favour of the new provisions.

This Act was repealed by the Police Act 1964, which was a major codification of policing law (itself since superseded). Current law carries forward the idea that constables must be sworn in by a JP, and the [required declaration](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1996/16/schedule/4) is recognizably a descendant of the 1842 version. Since that repeal, if not earlier, a JP no longer has a freestanding power to appoint a constable of their own choosing. There is no statute which authorizes them to do so, and any residual power under common law or a local Act would have been taken away by section 21 of the Act of 1842.

Further, the general policy direction of police legislation since 1842, and even earlier, has been in favour of constables being organized into a structure where they are accountable to chief constables, who are themselves answerable in some fashion to some democratic authority. (Presently, that would be a "policing and crime commissioner".) This is visible in section 15 of the Parish Constables Act. Looking at the assemblage of police-related laws, featuring the division of the country into "police areas" and so on, there does not seem to be any role for appointments to a common-law office of constable, outside of the comprehensive statutory framework.

There are various smaller police forces, but these all act according to specific statutory authority of their own. For example, the Mersey Tunnels Police have the office of constable because the County of Merseyside Act 1980 s.105(2) requires them to be attested as such before a JP.

---

<sup>1</sup> See Blackstone's *Commentaries on the Law of England* (1765) at 1.9.4; Halsbury's Laws of England vol. 84 (2019 ed.) on "The common law constable"; etc.

<sup>2</sup> The first legislative act about this is probably the Statute of Winchester (1285) which said that *en chescun hundred e fraunchise seyent eleus deus Conestables*, "in each hundred and franchise there shall be elected two constables", who were to inspect and report to justices of the peace regarding local compliance with the statute. A "hundred" and a "franchise" were local government units of Anglo-Saxon and Norman feudal origin respectively.

Comment: Hi Alex, may I ask what was your basic research process for figuring out the basic structure of the relevant legal framework from what I can only imagine as having  been fairly close to scratch?

Comment: The historical overview in Halsbury helped to understand the 19th C. transition to professional forces. From that, I wanted to identify when a JP stopped having discretion as to who to appoint. I still do not know that precisely, but by chance the 1842 act (which I turned to in order to find out how parish constables were chosen) turns out to contain the important repeal of any random leftover powers to appoint constable-like officers. That simplifies the question of what powers exist today.